# Express integral into elliptical form

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> How can i express the $\displaystyle \int\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4-1}}dx$

Try:  $x=\tan t, dx=\sec^2(t)dt$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{(\tan^2t-1)}{\sqrt{\tan^4t-1}}dt=\int\sqrt{\sin^2t-\cos^2t}dt =\int\sqrt{1-2\cos^2t}dt$

Could some help me how i express in elliptical form, Thanks

Comment: here is the Maple Output: $${\frac { \left( {x}^{2}-1 \right) x}{\sqrt { \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) 
 \left( {x}^{2}-1 \right) }}}+{\frac {i\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}\sqrt {-{x}^{2
}+1} \left( {\it EllipticF} \left( ix,i \right) -{\it EllipticE}
 \left( ix,i \right)  \right) }{\sqrt {{x}^{4}-1}}}
$$

Comment: Your last expression is already an [elliptic integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html), more or less. It is enough to enforce the substitution $t\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$.

Comment: Thanks jack and thanks doctor.